# Quantum circuit for the ZZ feature map

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, embedding

Havlicek et al. propose a feature map for embedding $n$-dimensional classical data on $n$ qubits: $U_{\phi(x)}H^{\otimes n}$, where
$$
U_{\phi(x)} = \exp (i \sum_{S \subseteq [n]} \phi_S(x) \prod_{i \in S} Z_i) \\
\phi_i(x) = x_i, \; \phi_{\{i, j\}}(x) = (\pi - x_0)(\pi - x_1)
$$
and $Z_i$ is a $Z$-gate on the $i$-th qubit.

I'm currently considering the 2-dimensional, 2-qubit case,
$$
U_{\phi(x)} = \exp(i x_0 Z_0 + i x_1 Z_1 + i (\pi - x_0) (\pi - x_1) Z_0 Z_1),
$$
and trying to find out, how do I get from the above definition to the circuit, as it is implemented in Qiskit:

```
     ┌───┐┌──────────────┐                                           
q_0: ┤ H ├┤ U1(2.0*x[0]) ├──■─────────────────────────────────────■──
     ├───┤├──────────────┤┌─┴─┐┌───────────────────────────────┐┌─┴─┐
q_1: ┤ H ├┤ U1(2.0*x[1]) ├┤ X ├┤ U1(2.0*(π - x[0])*(π - x[1])) ├┤ X ├
     └───┘└──────────────┘└───┘└───────────────────────────────┘└───┘
```

My reasoning for the first 2 $U1$ rotations is that since $\exp(i \theta Z) = RZ(2 \theta)$ up to global phase and $RZ$ is equivalent to $U1$ up to global phase, we might as well use $U1(2 \phi_i(x))$. Is that correct?

And if so, how do we then get $CX \; U1(2 \phi_{\{0, 1\}}(x)) \; CX$ from $\exp(i \phi_{\{0, 1\}}(x) Z_0 Z_1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of $U1(\lambda) $  in qiskit, it is [equivalent](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.U1Gate.html) to $RZ$ up up a phase factor .

Now note that: $$Z_0 Z_1 = Z \otimes Z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}  $$

since this is diagonal, we have that
$$ e^{-i\lambda Z_0Z_1} =  \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\lambda} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\lambda} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & e^{i\lambda} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-i\lambda}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} R_Z(2\lambda) & \boldsymbol{0}\\ \boldsymbol{0} & X R_Z(2\lambda)   X\end{pmatrix}  $$

since $XR_Z(2\lambda)  X =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\lambda} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\lambda} \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} e^{i\lambda} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\lambda} \end{pmatrix}   $

Thus, to implement  $e^{-i \lambda Z_0Z_1}$ we would have a circuit like:

[image]

Note that this circuit can be written as $CX \cdot (I \otimes R_Z ) \cdot CX$. Also by knowing this, you can check this explicitly as well, by first note that

$$ I \otimes R_Z(2\lambda) =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\lambda} & 0 \\ 0 &  e^{i\lambda}\end{pmatrix} =  
\begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\lambda} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\lambda} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & e^{-i\lambda} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\lambda}\end{pmatrix}
$$
then  $CX \cdot \big(I \otimes RZ(2\lambda) \big) \cdot CX$ is equal to
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\lambda} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\lambda} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & e^{-i\lambda} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\lambda}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\lambda} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\lambda} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & e^{i\lambda} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-i\lambda}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just one more question. Why can we go from $e^{i \lambda Z_0 Z_1}$ (as in $U_{\phi(x)}$) to $e^{-i \lambda Z_0 Z_1}$? Wouldn't that imply that $R_z(\lambda) = R_z(-\lambda)$, which seems to only be true for $\lambda = k \pi, \; k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I just realize that you are considering $e^{i\lambda ZZ}$ instead of $e^{-i \lambda ZZ}$. In such cases, the $RZ$ rotation gate should sandwiched between the two CNOT gates should be $RZ(-2\lambda)$ instead of $RZ(2 \lambda)$.

Comment: That's the issue. The circuit still uses $U1(\lambda)$ instead of $U1(-\lambda)$. Found a [relevant article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10467), where they're using the same circuit Qiskit does, however, they define $U1(\lambda) = diag\{1, e^{-i \lambda}\}$, which would solve the sign issue. Could it be that the direction of rotation doesn't really matter? I'm using this feature map to estimate the kernel $K(x, y) = \Phi(x) \Phi(y)$, by measuring $(U_{\phi(y)} H^{\otimes n})^\dagger U_{\phi(x)} H^{\otimes n}$. Since $K(x, y) = K(y, x)$ and $U1(\lambda)^\dagger = U1(-\lambda)$, it seems so?

Comment: Or, more simply put (since I've run out of space), we're still going to measure the same overlap $\Phi(x) \Phi(y)$, as long as we're consistently rotating in one direction, be it clockwise or counter-clockwise. What do you think?