# How can I change the default mapping function in ZZ feature map?

Tags: qiskit, programming, machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I am working with QSVM and have been reading a few things about this. I tried QSVM from the qiskit documentation as well. I also went through the link [Quantum circuit for the ZZ feature map](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17868/quantum-circuit-for-the-zz-feature-map) which beautifully explains the working of ZZ feature map to a great extent. Can someone suggest to me, how can I change this kernel to radial bias kernel or any other function like x^2+y^2?

Comment: are you asking how to run an kernel SVM using radial basis function (that is, completely classically? Or do you mean changing the `data_map_func` argument that performs classical preprocessing on input data to the ZZFeatureMap?

Comment: Also you don't want to use a kernel $k(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ - this is not positive definite (consider the dataset $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 1$ you'll see that the Gram matrix has a negative eigenvalue)

Comment: I am interested in knowing how the data_map_function can be applied? also i want to know how a poly kernel can be applied using ZZ feature map